# Abnormal memory usage behavior (periodic pulse)

Tags: windows-10, memory

I recently detected a strange memory behavior in my computer: **the memory usage nearly doubled all of a sudden and dropped to normal after a while. Such strange behavior repeated periodically, forming a sequence of pulses on the memory usage graph**. I tried to figure out the malicious process through resource monitor and task manager, but all monitored processes behaved.
When I tried to do a deeper exploration using code, the abnormal phenomenon disappeared. So I ended up here asking questions.
Here's a **[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/miRFu.png)** of the memory monitor in task manager (I don't have enough reputation to put the image directly in the question)
Some additional information about my environment:
**Operating System** : Windows 10 Professional 20H2
**Memory** : 8GB DDR4 2666MHz * 2
**External Devices** : Mobile Hard Drive(USB), Mouse(USB), Monitor(HDMI+TypeC)

Comment: well without perfmon or some other monitoring tool, there is no way to know

Answer (score 1):

Why "malicious'? Is it affecting operation or performance?

Windows has many maintenance tasks, such as disk optimization, malware scanning and indexing, that periodically start and stop. Further, some of these processes run only when the PC is idle, and as soon as one starts to check, the process stops. One term for this situation is *Heisenbug*: the process (or error) exists until it's observed -- running instrumentation causes it to stop.

The process names are often obscured under *svchost.exe*, so the particular operation may not be evident.

Comment: If it didn't affect my operation, I wouldn't have spotted it. When memory usage is at the peak of a pulse, everything seemed to get stuck: the cursor froze, the audio output noise, the keyboard failed to respond, etc.

Comment: Have you done virus scans with multiple tools? In addition to a full scan with your normal anti-malware suite (e.g., Defender), you can run a one-time scan with ESET (https://www.eset.com/us/home/online-scanner/) or Malwarebytes (https://www.malwarebytes.com/solutions/virus-scanner).